# Can I use Angular Flex-layout library for simple project?

Tags: html, angular, flexbox, gulp, angular-flex-layout

I'm building a simple project with html, scss and javascript, i'm using Gulp.js as well.

I was wondering if it would be possible and a good practice to use the [Angular Flex layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) library in the proyect.

**Note**: I need to finish it very quickly while maintaining a responsive layout and I thought using the library would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Angular and CSS are two separate topics so using a library that creates a dependency between these two concepts is something I would never recommend.
You can use Flex layouts with base CSS that has nothing to do with Angular.
Your learning curve will be easier that way because you can learn Flex without thinking about Angular, just like you can learn Angular without knowing about Flex.

Comment: I have some knowlege in angular and css but I thought it would be easier with the library since I dont have to write the full css but the attributes like: fxLayout="row"  instead

Comment: if fxLayout="row" is easier to you than something like class="flex-row", and you find it worth adding kilobytes of dependencies to your application, then go ahead. But your question was about best practices, so using a dependency that is bigger than what you likely need is not a best practice.